# Host node.js website

Tags: javascript, node.js, hosting, host

I have tried hosting my Node.js website on Heroku and Elastic Beanstalk, but both offer dynamic IP addresses while I need to use static IP address according to my DNS provider.

Which website is recommended for hosting node.js websites for free?

Answer (score 1):

I am hosting my blog at [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), I use a 512 RAM droplet with latest node.js 8.4 and mongodb 3.4 and It seems quite ok, very fast response time.

> The cheapest droplete comes at 5$/mo but usualy I pay 6$ but any way very good service.

Answer (score 0):

> Which website is recommended for hosting node.js websites for free?

None.  Pay for proper hosting.  It isn't that expensive... you can get $5/mo. cheap VPS on Digital Ocean or similar.  If you just need to host something for development purposes, the only workable free solution is to host it yourself on your own server on your own home internet connection.

> I need to use static IP address according to my DNS provider

Doubtful.  Try a CNAME record pointed at the hostname provided to you by Heroku or Elastic Beanstalk.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using AWS t2.micro servers for beginners, which will bring to the least possible cost or no cost. It is working pay as you go method which will also help you upgrade when your income or users starts to grow it is very convenient and economical.

It has the best deployment practices & easy as well. If you are stuck I can guide you.